# Spring boot internationalization always prefers English in english lang OS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have spring boot app with the beans needed for internationalization.

```
 @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName(CookieNames.LANG);
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale(Lang.DEFAULT_LANG.getLabel())); //label is "ru"
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(this.localeAgeCookie);
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor() {
        return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource());
    }
```

And there are files messages in Russian (messages.properties) and English(messages_en.properties), Russian is selected as default.
Language I change with POST request instead of interceptor by calling the following method.

```
public static void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Lang lang) {
    final LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, Locale.forLanguageTag(lang.getLabel()));

}
```

The problem is that when i call

```
 messageSourceAccessor.getMessage(key)
```

,
 and the key is located in both messages and messages_en files, I always get a message from messages_en even if I force the locale in the query like:

```
messageSourceAccessor.getMessage(key, new Locale("ru")).
```

I noticed that my colleague on the Russian lang based OS, there is no such problem. But on production and I have English OS.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is quite simple. It was enough to change the property **fallbackToSystemLocale** of the message source.

```
 messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
```

Comment: Great, works for me! I had the bizarre situation that printing out the locale in the thymeleaf template showed what I would expect, but the messageSource was not using the same locale.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to start your application with system parameters
`user.language=ru`
`user.country=RU`

note: I'm not sure if ru and RU are good values but that you probably know better than me

Comment: It works. But I think it's a questionable decision. Why initially he tries to take a message from messages_en.properties if the locale in the context of an explicitly specified as ru

Comment: I don't know what is the context of your application. If you provide some sample then I can look into it, but probably you are wrongly setting your locale. Try to look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229186/spring-save-locale-and-change-locale-when-user-logs-in). There is alwasys many options.