# MessageSource Spring: NotSerializableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using MessageSource to implement Internationalization in Spring.

I have something like this.

In my Config class:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return messageSource;
}
```

My Spring Bean

```
@Component
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private MessageSource messages;
}
```

When I run my Project I get this Exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
```

Can SomeOne please guides me how to resolve this.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229186/spring-save-locale-and-change-locale-when-user-logs-in)

Comment: can you paste the full log of the stack trace exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the information you have provided here, the problem is with your `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` class as it does not implement Serializable interface.

This causes by your `class MyClass implements Serializable` as variables in a Serializable class should be either `Serializable` or `transient`.

So according to your class either your `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` class should implement `Serializable` interface or in your MyClass, the variable should as follows

```
@Autowired(required=true)
private transient MessageSource messages;
```

Hope it helps